# MVC Routing with relative path as parameter - How to escape the default behavior of searching for a file when link ends with extension?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing, file-extension

I am looking for a way to make the MVC routing to hide upload path of a file, but considering it might be an html file that links to another html file I need to compensate for that.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "GetFile",
    url: "File/{id}/{*path}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "GetFile", id = UrlParameter.Optional, path = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

So this leading to a url for example:
    `http://example.com/Files/5/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/index.html`
and if a link is clicked on that page to lead to:     `http://example.com/Files/5/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/index2.html`

But currently my problem is that if I add any file extension in the mix it dies because it is looking for the file itself, when I need it to just pass it as a text variable.

Comment: Given the fact that MVC's primary purpose is to abstract the request/response model away from physical files, it is unclear what you are trying to do. Not to mention the potential security implications of allowing the end user to know the physical file locations. Why bother with physical files when you can do pretty much anything through MVC requests?

Comment: I am creating a type of content hosting, so I can't really escape give some sort of a path to the user, but cloaking it behind a handler (in this case the function GetFile) I can actually see if the file they are accessing they should have access to, this way I can also forbid cross-domain access and apply my own security.

Comment: Ok, but typically the way that is done is by creating or using a 3rd party Content Management System (CMS) to manage the content. This fits neatly within the context of MVC in order to leverage its security and other features. You are definitely going about things the hard way. StackOverflow is a good example of a CMS that uses MarkDown to generate HTML from user-driven content without resorting to uploading and hosting files outside of MVC.

Comment: I would agree, but I am working on a learning system implementing SCORM packages. Some scorm package contents are spread among different files and this is exactly the case I explained in this question. How would you suggest I go about reading these packages? The links are always relative. I wanted to open those files through the MVC handler I have written which takes care of the security and returns the requested file, but if I enter an extension in the link it just makes the system look for the file instead of requesting the handler. Those are new waters for me, so I am open for suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you describe "if I add any file extension in the mix it dies because it is looking for the file itself" is not an MVC problem, but due to the default web server settings.

In IIS, there are settings to control how specific file extensions are handled. `.html` files are served directly through the web server by default and thus ignored by MVC. You can override this behavior by changing the handlers from their default settings.

### 1. Change HTTP Handlers in web.config to Handle `.html` Extension

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>     
        <add name="HtmlFileHandler" path="*.html" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        <!-- other handlers... -->
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

### 2. Ensure `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` is `false`

Note this is the default so if this doesn't exist, don't add it.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

### 3. Add the Route

You have this (almost). But it probably doesn't make any sense to make `id` or `path` optional on the route. After all, what is it supposed to do if you don't supply the path? `id` can only be optional if it is not followed by path, so you would need to make another route to handle the no `id` case if it is indeed optional.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "GetFile",
    url: "File/{id}/{*path}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "GetFile" }
);
```

### 4. Route Existing Files

To route the files in their original location, you need to apply the setting to routing, otherwise you will get an error if the URL is the same as a physical file on disk.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "GetFile",
        url: "File/{id}/{*path}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "GetFile" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
}
```

Reference: https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/asp-net-mvc-routing-intercepting-file-requests-like-index-html-and-what-it-teaches-about-how-routing-works

Comment: Thank you, this will help me very much!